# Date order inconsistent in Jobs PDF CV

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Why are some dates in reverse order in my Stack Overflow CV?

Please see the highlights in the following image.

> June 2015 - October 2014

[image: CV PDF]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the report A.T.! We were not handling the case of forked repositories correctly, this should be fixed now.